# return the count of cases in JSON format + apex rest call

Tags: apex

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CaseByPhone/*')
global with sharing class CaseByPhone{

    @HttpGet
    global static Integer doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        caseId= req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Integer resultCount = [SELECT COUNT() From Case  WHERE Asset.Phone= :caseId];

     RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(result));

        return resultCount;
    }

}
```

But not working

Comment: What is not working? What do you expect and what is your actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wrapper/inner class to return as JSON:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CaseByPhone/*')
global with sharing class CaseByPhone{

    @HttpGet
    global static ResultWrapper doGet() {

        ResultWrapper objResultWrapper = new ResultWrapper();
        caseId= req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        objResultWrapper.count = [SELECT COUNT() From Case  WHERE Asset.Phone= :caseId];
        return objResultWrapper;
    }

    public class ResultWrapper {
        public Integer count = 0;
    }

}
```

If you are returning a String, you can use [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) to the object and return the result string.